# SQL server insert same value to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

How can I insert the same value to multiple rows?

For example, I want to insert $10 dollars to all customers bill table Bill_Amount column where customer is equal to specific service type

I want to do it in SQL Server.

Comment: It will be an `update` and not an `Insert`

Comment: Are you sure you want to insert and not update the bill amount ???

Comment: no  i don't want to update i want to insert Mureinik understo my question

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a `customers` table, you could use the insert-select syntax and select a literal of 10$:

```
INSERT INTO bill_amount (customer_id, bill_amount)
SELECT customer_id, 10
FROM   customers
WHERE  service_type = 'some_service'
```

Comment: These low effort level questions shouldn't be given answer!!

Comment: this is the idea i wanted but can i use select with insert PLZ help am new to  databases

Comment: Thnx alot Mureinik you helped me to much and so sorry if that was a Low effort question next time i will give more effort to my questions and make it  clear and precise ass possible   Thanks to all of u